# KDE with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, kde, sddm

I have installed kde on my Ubuntu installation trough `sudo apt install kde-full`, but I still have some question about updates, is there any issue removing Ubuntu desktop from it using `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-software software-properties-gtk nautilus update-manager gnome-system-monitor`? And what about new upgrades, for example, when Ubuntu 22.04 launch, will it upgrade just fine? Do I need to keep one or is better to keep the two? When I enter in ubuntu desktop, there's a lot of sddm/kde related errors.

Comment: It may be simpler to perform a fresh install of Kubuntu.

Comment: You can install a number of desktops on your Ubuntu base (second without issue, sometimes a third without issue though installing more will create issues in my experience) and whilst it may complicate *release-upgrade* (a lot more space is required for download, more bandwidth used in upgrade, install etc) it still occurs normally.  You can remove desktops too (inc. Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME)) though I've always used the full desktop (ie. `kubuntu-desktop`) so I don't know if you'll have issues only having KDE (`kde-full` (not Kubuntu installed).

Comment: `kde-full` is the KDE5 apps; https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kde-full not the full disk

Comment: In this case, if I install it trough `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`, even with KDE already installed on my Ubuntu, will it be better?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use special task package.

Use command below

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop^
```

In the above command note the `^` symbol, it marks a special task package.

Comment: At this case, what will it do to my current desktop and how it will affect kde/Ubuntu already installed on my computer

Comment: It will install fullest KDE as it shipped in Kubuntu.